# How to decode video with mime type application/octet-stream using mediaCodec decoder

Tags: android, mime-types, mime, android-mediacodec, decoder

I need to decode videos into frames. I am able to do this for mime type **video** but it doesn't work with **application/octet-stream**.

```
for (int i = 0; i < extractor.getTrackCount(); i++) {
                MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);
                String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
                System.out.println(mime);
                if (mime.startsWith("application/")) {
                    extractor.selectTrack(i);
                    try {
                        decoder = MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(mime);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    decoder.configure(format, null, null, 0);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

The error I get is below.

```
E/libc: Access denied finding property "ro.kirin.product.platform"
W/HwExtendedCodec: The mime is not in hisi extended mime.
W/Thread-3: type=1400 audit(0.0:81515): avc: denied { read } for pid=23409 name="u:object_r:product_platform_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=15947 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c111,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:product_platform_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
W/MediaCodec-JNI: try to release MediaCodec from JMediaCodec::~JMediaCodec()...
    done releasing MediaCodec from JMediaCodec::~JMediaCodec().
I/QarthLog: [PatchStore] createDisableExceptionQarthFile
I/QarthLog: [PatchStore] create disable file for com.example.mp4decoder uid is 10367
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-3
    Process: com.example.mp4decoder, PID: 23409
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to initialize application/octet-stream, error 0xfffffffe
        at android.media.MediaCodec.native_setup(Native Method)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.<init>(MediaCodec.java:1864)
        at android.media.MediaCodec.createDecoderByType(MediaCodec.java:1809)
        at com.example.mp4decoder.MainActivity$PlayerThread.run(MainActivity.java:108)
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, MediaCodec just support Audio or Video Format. I do not think "application/octet-stream" is a video format. Video format should start with "video/", like "video/avc","video/hevc" etc.
I think you got "application/octet-stream" because the stream is not a video stream or   MediaExtractor does not know the stream format.

Comment: Hi Dangfeng,

Thanks for the reply. Actually it is a video, I am able to play it on exoplayer or any other standard video player, so I guess it can be decoded. Also just checked around, application/octet-stream is a valid mime type for videos. Would be happy to get further help.

Comment: How many tracks the video have，and do you know which track standard video player played? You can enumerate all MediaCodec and get their supported formats. Maybe there is no MediaCodec can handle "application/octet-stream" format

Comment: Tried that too, returns null.

Comment: Which returns null? Could you provide a link to the video?

Comment: @ShriHari what if you force to set a mime type manually like "video/avc" or "video/hevc"or something else?

Comment: Hey Dangfeng,
I tried to create the decoder by finding a suitable codec for the given format from a list of all the available codecs. And then tried to create the codec using MediaCodec.createByCodecName(Codecname). But this returns null for the application/octet-stream video. Works fine for the the other videos which have a mime type of 'video/'. Here is the link for the video - https://www.dropbox.com/s/57vamzkuiebgpht/demo_03.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Hey easy_breezy,
Tried that too. I get this error.
`W/HwExtendedCodec: The mime is not in hisi extended mime.
I/ACodec: In onAllocateComponent create compenent, codec name: OMX.hisi.video.decoder.avc
E/ACodec: [OMX.hisi.video.decoder.avc] configureCodec returning error -22
E/MediaCodec: Codec reported err 0xffffffea, actionCode 0, while in state 3
E/MediaCodec: configure failed with err 0xffffffea, resetting...
I/ACodec: In onAllocateComponent create compenent, codec name: OMX.hisi.video.decoder.avc
E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

Comment: I tried this video, got format {track-id=1, durationUs=33366666, mime=application/octet-stream, language=und, max-input-size=793435}. And I analyzed the video with ffprobe, got format hevc with some errors. VLC player can play but there are many errors, too. I think there are two problems: First, the file contains some errors. Second, MediaExtractor not handle these error correctly, so not set mime to "video/hevc", and not set "csd-0" and "csd-1" in MediaFormat. I do not think you can decode the video, unless you create a MediaFormat correctly. Or you can just use ExoPlayer.

Comment: Hi danfeng, Could you please tell me the work around for creating the MediaFormat correctly. I need these kind of videos to be decoded. I am sure its possible. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is a little difficult. You need jni and ffmpeg to do this. Are you familiar with ffmpeg? You can reference mediacodecdec.c in ffmpeg.

Comment: Hi dangfeng
No i dont have an idea about ffmpeg. Is it possible by injecting format features using format.setString or setInteger? or is there any other easier workaround?

Comment: Hi dangfeng. I just tried setting the mime type to video.hevc using format.setString(KEY_MIME_TYPE,"video/hevc). It creates a decoder. But now I get a timeout in the output buffers. I was told that this could happen because for the difference in the presentation order and encoding order of the frames, and that the output keeps waiting for the frame in the presentation order.